# Android/ phonegap - Stretching my background image to fit screen

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, background-image

I have tried various differnt things however none of them seem to work. I am using inline CSS and simply want to add a background which stetches to the screen size. I am currently using the following code within my body tag:

```
<body onLoad="onBodyLoad();" style="background:url(images/blue_bg.png);">
```

My image is 400 x 300, but need to be streched to as far as 1200 x 1000.

Hope someone can help (have tried background-size:100%).

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this CSS3 code:

```
body{
    background: url(images/blue-bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If this doesn't work you can try :

[Other CSS techniques](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

[jQuery techniques](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/quick-tip-resizing-images-based-on-browser-window-size/)

Comment: Just noticed that your fix works perfectly on my Android Archos, however does not work on my Android phone? Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: You may want to test with `background-size: contain;` instead of `cover`. Both are working well.