# how to set background image for complete screen in phone gap android?

Tags: android, css, cordova

in android version of phone gap background image is not fully covering the screen though having high resolution image

```
body {
                background-image: url("../www/img/tracker_bg.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
```

though using attachmend fixed and changed ever style to set background but for some screen it is not covering full screen as back ground

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS3 Code:

```
body{
    background: url(img/tracker_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Help From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381264/android-phonegap-stretching-my-background-image-to-fit-screen)